# Given two discrete random variables $X_1$ and $X_2,$ can we express $E[\max(X_1,X_2)]$ in terms of $P(\max(X_1,X_2)\leq x)?$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given two discrete random variables $X_1$ and $X_2,$ if we want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\min(X_1,X_2)],$ it is useful to consider the identity 
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty P(X\geq x)$$
as 
$$P(\min(X_1,X_2)\geq x) = P(X_1\geq x) P(X_2\geq x).$$

> Question: Can we express $E[\max(X_1,X_2)]$ in terms of $P(\max(X_1,X_2)\leq x)?$

Since we know that 
$$P(\max(X_1,X_2)\leq x) = P(X_1\leq x) P(X_2\leq x),$$
it might simplify calculations greatly.

Comment: you could always say that $P(max(X_1, X_2) \ge x) = 1-P(max(X_1, X_2) \le x)$ but not sure how helpful this is

Comment: I am more interested in calculating expectation of maximum instead of probability of maximum...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to answer your question in a way that's useful, but here are three different thoughts that may be relevant.

For shorthand, let $U = \min(X_1, X_2), V = \max(X_1, X_2)$.

**First:** As @SandeepSilwal pointed out,

$$E[V] = \sum_{v \ge 1} P(V \ge v) = \sum_{v \ge 1} (1 - P(V < v))$$

So that technically answers your question, although the "usefulness" is questionable.  Note that $v\to \infty \implies P(V < v) \to 1$, which explains why we cannot separate the last sum into $\sum_{v \ge 1} 1 - \sum_{v \ge 1} P(V < v)$ which would be a kind of "$\infty - \infty$".

**Second:** If what you really want is "easy" calculation, and you consider the formula for $E[U]$ to be "easy", then this extra step should make $E[V]$ also easy:

$$X_1 + X_2 = U + V \implies E[V] = E[X_1] + E[X_2] - E[U]$$

**Third:** You never mentioned this, but the formula $E[Z] = \sum_{z=1}^\infty P(Z \ge z)$ only works if $Z \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, i.e. $Z$ is non-negative integral.  It does not work e.g. if $Z$ can take negative integral values.  This immediately implies that, if your original $X,Y$ take only non-positive integral values, then the formula for min works for $-X, -Y$ and so it also works for $\max(X,Y) = - \min(-X, -Y)$.

$$E[V] = -E[\min(-X,-Y)] = -\sum_{v \ge 1} P(\min(-X,-Y) \ge v) \\
=-\sum_{v \ge 1} P(-X \ge v)P(-Y \ge v) = -\sum_{v \ge 1} P(X \le -v) P(Y \le -v)$$